# SQL sum colums to merge data

Tags: sql

I have a table with a list of sites, and how many hits they have as you see in the picture:

[image: SQL table]
The same site will appear many times, so I need to sum up the sites and the hits, that is to say, I want the site to show once with all the hits and not multiple times in the result.

So, for example, `/sites/test1` with the total number of hits.

How do I make the correct SQL statement for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
    Stem
    ,SUM(Hits) AS Total_hits
FROM <your_table>
GROUP BY Stem
```

Comment: I dont know if I want to cry or laugh right now. Yes, I did the other way around and did sum on stem, brainfreeze of the year. 

Thank you for the quickest reply ever.

Comment: It happens to the best of us ... Cheers!